# Stackshot Apple Tv 4

Tags: appletv

I was watching some Netflix on my Apple TV 4th generation, when I by mistake sat on my remote, suddenly a message appeared in the upper right corner, the message was like “Hold the button to activate stackshot in X seconds”, I can’t remember the specific text but it was something like the above mentioned.

So what is Stackshot? What is it used for,? And how do I activate it again?

Apple TV 4th gen. tvOS 11

Comment: I don't think you need to activate it, it looks like a debugging tool: https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stackshot.1.html

Comment: Thank you, but why did I get a message about it, at the moment I stopped pressing some buttons?

Comment: I had the same scenario watching Netflix and I rolled on my remote and the same message appeared with hold button for 6 seconds

Comment: I found this when my little daughter was playing with the remote :D

Comment: The key press in question is play/pause + minus(-), the lowest two buttons on the remote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Apple Developer documentation stack shot is to used collect all kind of information about a crashed process.

Apparently you used a button combination that activates Stackshots. On iOS it’s works like this (assuming tvOS works almost the same);

> **Stackshots**
>
> For freezes or hangs with your iOS device, or when stackshots are requested, please follow the instructions below to capture and attach them.
>
> Press the Home button and either volume button on the device at the same time
>
> Note: Press the button combo several times to capture a series of stackshots

https://download.developer.apple.com/iOS/iOS_Logs/Stackshot_Logging_Instructions_iOS.pdf

Comment: By holding down the home button and the volume up button for 10 seconds, and then releasing the buttons gives a message “Log archive send to Apple  (LINE BREAK) Send 1 logarchive to Apple”

Comment: And by holding down Play Pause and volume down, a message with the text “Analyzing...” appears

Comment: And just by clicking Play pause and volume, I get the message that my original question was about

Comment: The "Play/pause" button plus volume down will work to save a stackshot in tv os as of Dec 03, 2018